# How to create a full screen div on landing page

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website, however I would like the website to have a full screen div (Like this: http://peet.io)
However I do not know what is wrong with my code, I have tried googling several times, but still no help.

This is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/6p3dk2yo/

```
.introduction {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('../images/header.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: absolute;
}
```

That is my `introduction` css code.
However it only show's my `test` div and not my `introduction` div which is what I need the most, is not showing, the 'test' div is making it hidden.

If anyone knows how i can fix this then please say:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because setting `height: 100%` simply means "stretch to the height of element's content". And since it is an empty `<div>` element, a height of 100% simply computes to 0px.

What you can do though, is to use `vw` or `vh` units when it comes to dimensions (see [browser compatibility and support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)) that have to be calculated relative to the viewport size:

```
.introduction {
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('../images/header.jpg') no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/6p3dk2yo/3/

Even better, is that you can also use `max-height` or `min-height` to control how big the element should be when it comes to smaller, mobile viewports through the `@media` conditional statement.

Comment: Thanks, how will i make it so the section main has the height of 100% and then have all my main content in the section so it display s underneath the introduction section?

Comment: @Unique I don't understand your question, there is no main section as you have mentioned in your original markup.

Answer (score 0):

Your `introduction` div has a `height: 100%;` but it's 100% of nothing.

If you put some content in your div, like in this **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6p3dk2yo/4/)** then you'll be able to see the background image.

If you don't want any content in the div, then you should change height to a fixed pixel amount, like `height: 500px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` technically has no content, so it is in fact 100% of 0px (content size). If you want to stick with the percentages and keep things responsive as you are, why not throw an actual image in that `div` containter? Check out this Jfiddle. -> http://jsfiddle.net/6p3dk2yo/

```
<body>
    <section class="introduction"></section>
    <section class="test"><img src='../images/header.jpg' alt='header' /></section>
    <script src="javascript/smoothscroll.js"></script>
</body>
```